# MediaPlayer.play() ends abruptly

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Here is my code:

```
    public void run() {

        String filePath = queue.poll();

        // Nothing more to play
        if (filePath == null) {
            isPlaying = false;
            return;
        }

        isPlaying = true;
        File file = new File(filePath);
        String uriString = file.toURI().toString();
        player = new MediaPlayer(new Media(uriString));
        player.play(); 
        player.setOnEndOfMedia(this);
    }
```

As you can see, run() is called repeatedly. On every call, it gets the head element from the queue and plays it.

Sometimes it works, and sometimes play ends abruptly, with onEndOfMedia never firing.

The snippet does not show it, but I did try overriding onError, catching exceptions, etc. On occasion, the play still just ends abruptly.

Perhaps I should be firing it from a particular thread?

Edit: it's too early to say for sure, but making player a field variable might have solved the problem. Was my player garbage collected while playing?

While at it: is this the correct way of doing things? Does it introduce any memory leaks?

Comment: Maybe you are getting an error. Just set an error handler on the MediaPlayer instance by calling player.setOnError(/*error handler runnable*/). See if it works with no errors.
You might set another error handler on the media instance as well.

Comment: Try ensuring any existing player is disposed, by calling `if (player != null) { player.dispose(); }` immediately before `player = new MediaPlayer(...);`.

Comment: @Amin, I did try setOnError, as stated in my question.

Comment: Thank you @James_D 1, great advice!

Comment: @IrinaRapoport Yes you're right. can't understand from your question you have tried both setOnError methods on the two different objects.

Comment: @Amin, ah you mean setting onError on `Media`? Nope, did not do it. Should I? Could it catch something `Player.onError` would not catch, mid-play? E.g. with play starting and ending abruptly?

Comment: @IrinaRapoport I'm just guessing in fact. Not sure if it really helps.

Comment: @IrinaRapoport BTW, It might look (an actually be) irrelevant to your case, however, I once figured out that fx media player is not going to play some file formats correctly, e.g., .mp3 files were not played at all. It's been passed along time (a year probably) and I did not test it again.

Comment: Seems to play mp3 fine now, ever since I made player a field, as opposed to a local variable. I suspect something was being garbage-collected.